# C++ regex: split the string

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to search and split a string based on regex. Suppose I have a string named var which looks like

```
|   | | |-DeclRefExpr 0x5d91218 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x5d91120 'y' 'int'
```

Now I would like to split this into

```
|   | | |-DeclRefExpr 0x5d91218 <col:5> 
int
 lvalue Var 0x5d91120 
y

int
```

I know that the regex will be something like [^']* but I cant figure out how I can do it. What I have tried so far is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::string var = "    |   | | |-DeclRefExpr 0x5d91218 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x5d91120 'y' 'int'";

    std::regex rgx("[^']*");
    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_search(var.begin(), var.end(), match, rgx)){
        cout << match[3] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something like `[^']*'[^']*'[^']*'[^']*'[^']*'[^']*'`, plus capture groups in the appropriate places?

Comment: (.*)'(.*)'(.*)'(.*)'.*'(.*)' matches your requirement on http://regexpal.com/, std::regex might behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I can't test this code, but it can perhaps work.

```
std::string var = "|   | | |-DeclRefExpr 0x5d91218 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x5d91120 'y' 'int'";
std::regex wsaq_re("\\s*'|'+\\s*(?!')"); 
std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(var.begin(), var.end(), wsaq_re, -1),
    std::sregex_token_iterator(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: you can test your code on Coliru using clang and libc++, like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0b5fd383bc227fc

Comment: @pepper_chico: Thanks for the tip. I'm not an expert with C++, but I suppose that Coliru doesn't have all the libraries available. But thanks anyway, since I don't imagine that an online tool exists for compiled languages. Julia Roberts is 46 year old and always pretty, how it is possible? This is my futur (and first) question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @CasimiretHippolyte's method, you can also use `regex_search()`:

```
const regex r("(.*)'(.*)'(.*)'(.*)'(.*)'(.*)'");  
smatch sm;

if (regex_search(var, sm, r))
{
    for (int i=1; i<sm.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << sm[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

See it live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/494ab2e0f1c5d420